# jQuery and Wordpress changing css depending on the page selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress

I have a menu and depending on which page the user is currently on, I would like a border to show up under that menu item. For example if the user is on the home page, there would be a blue border underneath the home text on the navigation bar.

I am having trouble figuring out what page the user is on using jQuery.

Normally I would use CSS and on each page manually change the class in the html but since I'm dealing with Wordpress I can't change the ids unless I work with a walker but I figured I would give it a try with jQuery.

I tried setting each page as a variable such as:

```
var homeUrl = 'http://example.com/';

if (document.URL.is(homeUrl)) {
    $('#link-one').css('border-bottom', '1px solid #000');
};
```

Comment: Uh, WordPress already adds a great variety of active classes to its menus. You can even style a menu item that represents the parent of a page/post that you're on.

Comment: To be honest I got thrown into Wordpress kicking and screaming because of a client and I'm trying to learn the codex in about a couple days. Could you tell me where I'd go about finding that information?

Comment: It's right in the HTML - if you're on the home page, just look at all the classes that are added to the active `<li>`. The most directly useful is probably `current_page_item`, but there are other as well for different situations.

Answer (score -1):

Please try use plugin [Zia3 CSS JS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/zia3-css-js/screenshots/) :D